# Oracle Forms 12c key next item not running on execute query

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-forms

I am running oracle forms 12c
I have a client_id, client name, and contact number fields where if I type client_id it gets the clients name and contact number and those fields get populated

but when I execute_query I mean press ctrl+F11 I do not get those fields populated I have to manually press the tab key from the client_id field to get those populated

This is when I create a new record
[image]

This is when I execute the query
[image]

By the way, it is a master detail form and the same is happening it's not getting the product name  and pcs

How do I get those please help

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "post-query" trigger on record level and fill in those fields.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese  https://www.slideshare.net/atothman/oracle-forms-les18  slide 9 ?